# How does measurement error affect the standard error of regression coefficients?

Tags: statistics, regression, applications, regression-analysis

How does inclusion of the measurement error in the model, as
$$Y_i + \varDelta_i = bX_i + \varepsilon_i$$
affect the standard error of least square estimators $\hat{b}$ of coefficients $b$?

If I obtain a least squares fit from $Y_i = bX_i + \varepsilon_i$ and then later want to incorporate $\varDelta$, is it possible to modify my standard error of $\hat{b}$ to obtain the right value?

(You can assume that $\varDelta \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.)

Comment: Seems to me unbiased random measurement error just gets included in $s_{y|x}^2.$ Can you give the source or context of this problem? Can you clarify the difference you see between $\Delta_i$ and $\epsilon_i$? Are you trying to separate measurement error from subject variation? Maybe need a model that accounts for repeated measures on each subject. Why no y-intercept? That is, why regression through the origin? If possible, please edit Question to provide context along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can move $\Delta_{i} $ to the right-hand side and write $$Y_{i} = bX_{i} + (\varepsilon _{i} - \Delta_{i}) $$.

As long as $\Delta_{i}$ is independent and identically distributed (i.i.d) and uncorrelated with $X_{i}$, the OLS estimate of the $b$ will be BLUE, that is, the estimate of $b$ will be unbiased. So you don't have to modify the standard error of $\hat{b}$.

This is a case of **Measurement Error in the Dependent Variable** and it is not a problem because of the above explanation. While your estimator isn't biased you will still lose efficiency as you'll have more noise on the left-hand side.

On the other hand, if it was **Measurement Error in the Independent Variable**, then your estimator will be biased.